# curve the edges of a rectangle

Tags: css

the css below will create a rectangle fill it with these col0ur #F6F6F6 but i want to curve the edge of the rectangle.

```
.bold {
border: solid 1px #e7e7e7; 
background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work in modern browsers

```
border:1px solid #aaac62;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px;
/** hack for IE6+ */
behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
```

Get your [border-radio.htc](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc&can=2&q=)

Comment: Does that work in IE?  What is the lowest version of IE will that work in?

Comment: AFAIK the `-webkit-border-radius` is only necessary for older versions of Safari/Chrome, which now respect the CSS3 `border-radius`. Also I don't believe IE will render rounded corners at all (at least through IE8; I don't know about 9).

Comment: CSS3Pie is better than the older border-radius.htc. Get it from here: http://css3pie.com/